# How do I know if the MFT is complete in my recovery of NTFS drive?

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, ntfs, ddrescue

I've been running ddrescue on a failed NTFS drive.  I don't remember what's on the drive, but I doubt it's important.

GNU `ddrescue` was able to recover about 80% of the drive easily, but then is very slow at recovering the rest.  It has bad sectors throughout the whole drive in a repeating pattern, so it will take eons to scrape every bit of data off the drive:

[image: ddrescueview showing many errors in repeating pattern]

There are bits of good data in the middle of each bad chunk (which are also in a repeating pattern):

[image: one bad chunk with small good parts in the middle]

but it is taking days to get through even the first bad chunk, and there are thousands of such chunks.

So I want to just confirm that the files on the drive are unimportant and give up.

I cannot mount the drive image as is.  It says

```
$MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 0).
Failed to mount '/dev/loop42': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

If I run `ntfsfix` I am able to mount the drive and see folders and files:

```
$MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 0).
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors...
Processing $MFT and $MFTMirr...
Reading $MFT... OK
Reading $MFTMirr... 
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 0: Invalid argument
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 0: Invalid argument
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 0: Invalid argument
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 0: Invalid argument
OK
Comparing $MFTMirr to $MFT... FAILED
Correcting differences in $MFTMirr record 0...OK
Correcting differences in $MFTMirr record 1...OK
Correcting differences in $MFTMirr record 2...OK
Correcting differences in $MFTMirr record 3...OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Setting required flags on partition... OK
Going to empty the journal ($LogFile)... OK
Checking the alternate boot sector... FIXED
NTFS volume version is 3.1.
NTFS partition /dev/loop43 was processed successfully.
```

So then I can mount it, and everything I can see is unimportant stuff that I have duplicate copies of.

But how do I know if it is listing *all* the files and folders that were on the drive?

Is there some way to view the $MFT and $MFTMirr and `vbindiff` them and manually correct any missing bits in one by using the copy in the other?  I read that the MFT is scattered throughout the drive.  How do I know if it recovered all of the MFT?

Comment: "But how do I know if it is listing all the files and folders that were on the drive?" - You don't, but unless the bad sectors are at the start of the drive, there is a good chance the MFT isn't corrupt.  `chkdsk` has a habit of fixing errors with the MFT, if there is a problem, this creates orphan files obviously.  If i have the correct table, the MFT would have an offset of 0x30 bytes on the partition.  If there isn't any corruption with the MFT (Describes all files on the volume) filename within those bytes you should be fine.

Comment: @Ramhound The first bad part starts at 35.81 MB. It's a single partition image with the NTFS partition starting at 1048576 (2048*512 B sectors)

Comment: You could create a image of the first 35 MB of data, then mount the image within a hex editor, which would contain both $MFTMirr and $MFT and view any differences that way.  But the output of the command you ran clearly resolved any differences already if that was the disk itself.

Comment: @Ramhound The command I ran was on the NTFS partition on the image of the drive.  How do I know that it "clearly resolved any differences"? (as opposed to ignoring parts that were missing, etc.)  How do I know how to find the MFTMirr and MFT locations?

Comment: @Ramhound I found the `ntfsinfo` tool, which tells the cluster location of $MFT (beginning of partition) and $MFTMirr (middle of partition) and was able to view them in a hex editor.